# qsort an array of strings, compare

Tags: c, arrays, string, qsort

I am trying to figure out how to use qsort with an array of strings.  My code looks like this.

```
char words[500][256];

int numOfWords; // this is calculated above

int sortWordList() {
    int length = sizeof(words) / sizeof(char *);
    qsort(words, length, sizeof(char*), compare);

}

int compare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
    const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char *pb = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(pa,pb);
}
```

However, I get a "Access violation reading location 0x###.." everytime and I dont know whats wrong.  Can anyone spot my problem?

EDIT: Thanks for the wonderful help.  You guys are always the best.

Comment: Hint: a two-dimensional array of `char` is not the same as an array of pointers to `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not casting your `const void *` to `const char *` properly, to do so, use instead:

```
const char *pa = (const char *)a;
const char *pb = (const char *)b;
```

Plus `compare()` should be above `sortWordList()` as you're using it in `sortWordList()`.

Comment: OK, so now the list gets sorted, but if I only have 90 elements in the list, the last 410 elements of empty space show up first.  Is there a way to have my data show up first?  (FIXED).